# Check if $\vec F$ is a conservative field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

I'm trying to check if $R/r$ is conservative feild

where $R=-x\hat i+y\hat j$ and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

*Attempt:*

$$R/r=\underbrace{\frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}_{M}i+\underbrace{\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}_{N}j$$

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}$$

$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=\frac{\color{red}-xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}$$

Since $$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\ne \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$

$R/r$ is not conservative field I think that I'm wrong

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: Correct! the field is not conservative.

Comment: Ok, thank you vey much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.  There's a simple lemma which states that if the (scalar) curl of a vector field is non-zero, then the field is non-conservative.

Just as an FYI, some people mistakingly believe that the inverse of this statement is also true.  But as it turns out a vector field being curl-free is not enough to say that it *is* conservative.  However with the additional constraint that the domain of the vector field is simply connected, then we could say that such a vector field is conservative.